# Checking new guid (unique identifiers) values in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm always using LINQ so I forgot how to check value in stored procedure whether it equals to 'new guid()' in C# or not

Is this correct

```
where (@SearchCategory = '000000-0000-0000-0000' )
```

or what???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'000000-0000-0000-0000' is not a 'new guid'.  It is the value that is returned by `Guid.Empty`

Why don't you just use parametrized queries, and pass Guid.Empty to the parameter as a value ?

Comment: very strange why there are no support for this! they can add a function checks this easily,however thank you

Answer (score 1):

in .NET Guid is a class and it has static method to create a new GUID

```
Guid.NewGuid(); // This will return new guid 
Guid.Empty;  // This will return the 000000.... type value which is a empty guid value
```

Answer (score 0):

`Guid.NewGuid()` holds a different value each time you call it.

When checking if the value holds a 'empty' Guid (uniqueidentifier) use `'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'`

(thats 8-4-4-4-12 zero's)